# error TS2552: Cannot find name 'VBArray'. in angular

Tags: excel, angular, vba, typescript, npm-install

I have code like below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
toJSArray(vba) {
            var vbarray = new VBArray(vba);
            var d = vbarray.dimensions();

            var dims = [];
            var base = [];
            var params = [];

            for (var i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
                dims.push(vbarray.ubound(i) - vbarray.lbound(i) + 1);
                base.push(vbarray.lbound(i));
                params.push(vbarray.lbound(i));
            }
...
}
```

As VBArray is not inbuild in angular. I have used following cmd to remove complile time error.

```
npm install --save @types/windows-script-host
```

But when I do ng build it gives me an error like "can not find name VBArray"
What I am missing or What to do to resolve this issue??

Comment: This object is a Microsoft extension and is only supported in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `declare const VBArray:any;` below your imports. This will take care of the compile error. Of course, you will have to take care of the object being present at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

in tsconfig.app.json file you need to add 'window-script-host' in types

```
{
 "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
"module": "es2015",
"types": ["windows-script-host"],  <-- add this
 },
"exclude": [
"src/test.ts",
"**/*.spec.ts"
]
}
```